# If statement in value class

Tags: scala

i need to validate the parameter of my value class (below) . But i get an error

> this statement is not allowed in value class

at compile time , is there a way around this ? Thanks.

```
case class Size(val size: Long) extends AnyVal { 
   if (size < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException; // error
   def +(s: Size): Size =Size(size + s.size)
}
```

Comment: I guess your problem is `size` parameter. Because value class can't be parameter of another value of another value class.

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/value-classes.html, namely the part "C may not have initialization statements."

Comment: Sèe this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33136558/validations-in-value-classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Value class is a wrapper around an existing object, so Scala doesn't in fact instantiate value class object, but use underlying object instead (that's why [SIP-15](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/value-classes.html) exists in the first place). Hence there is no place to put initialization code and runtime check of `size` is simply not possible.